# ER diagram with some specific conditions

Tags: database, entity-relationship

Say I have 2 relations: `User` and `Location` which is connected by the relation `going to`. Now, `going to` has an attribute called `date`. How do I draw the diagram in the case that a user can be at most only one location on exactly one date? Multiple users can go to multiple locations but the `date` attribute enforces kind of a uniqueness condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think the problem lies in data modeling in a conceptual model, but in the physical model. The conceptual model for this situation would be as follows:

[image]

"Going to" here would be considered an event, a moment when a user visits a (any) location. As we have a N-N relationship here, there is no problem to define a attribute / property in the created event (the relationship created). This will result in a table with two foreign keys. This table tells you what date a user visited a location.

Now, talking about the restriction imposed ... Yes, we have a restriction here, and that would be considered a SQL constraint. For a person to visit only one place on a certain date, you can:

- Define the columns "user" and "date" in "VISITS" table as a
  composite primary key.
- Define the columns "user" and "date" in "VISITS" table are
  unique in a composite form, and then use a surrogate key, for
  instance.

Anyhow, you get such a restriction with these two columns as being unique, which will result in the following case:

[image]

In this table (the VISITS table) you can not repeat the same user and the same date. The result is that a user can only visit one place on a date.

---

There is also another way to solve this problem. You could apply some data validation when new data were entered into the database (adding new visits records). This approach might be better if the number of visits per date increase. My advice is to analyze your needs and see if a change / maintenance in the future is something likely. If so, consider this.

Despite the validation data be something possible, remember that your database is the last line of defense against data inconsistency. Data inconsistency is one of the worst problems in a system because it may compromise it completely. Therefore, you should not do just validations as countermeasure for inconsistency. A database securely mounted DOES NOT ALLOW inconsistent data. A client user can receive the world in error messages when trying to do illegal actions, but corrupted data is never saved.

Unfortunately I do not have a firm knowledge about setting restrictions, rules, and constraints on databases, but be sure to research the subject 
if your needs change. When creating a database, it is ideal that in addition to creating tables, relationships, triggers, stored procedures, you also create certain restrictions. These are the rules defined in the database that make it virtually always consistent.

Hope I have helped in some way. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `date` qualifies as an attribute in this case.  An attribute is a function from an entity (or relationship) set to a value set, but `date` isn't determined by `User` and `Location`.  Rather, `date` is a subject of the relation, just like `User`, so I consider `date` to be an entity.  `Location` is more like an attribute in this example.

[image: User-Location-Date]